# Extracting XML attributes and structuring python

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

I hope it is not a repetitive question since I couldn't find one in this community.

I have the following simple XML structure and I would like to extract and structure it.

```
<Tables>
  <Table ID = '1', Row = '3', Column = '5'>  
     <Text> Example 1 </Text>    
  </Table>

 <Table ID = '2', Row = '4', Column = '3'>
    <Text> Example 2 </Text>
</Tables>
```

I would like to structure it and get the following table.

```
ID   Row   Column  Text
1    3       5      Example 1
2    4       3      Example 2
```

I tried it something below

```
xml_file = 'example.xml'

tree = lxml.etree.parse(xml_file)

xml_id= {}
xml_row= {}
xml_column = {}

for example in tree.iter("Table"):
#                                
    get_id = example.attrib['ID']
    get_rows = example.attrib['Rows']
    get_columns = example.attrib['Columns']

    xml_id[get_id] = []
    xml_row[get_rows] = []
    xml_column[get_columns] = []

    xml_id[get_id].append(example.text)
    xml_row[get_rows].append(example.text)
    xml_column[get_columns].append(example.text)

df_id = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in get_id.items()]))   
df_row = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in xml_row.items()]))   
df_columns = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in xml_column.items()])) 

result = pd.concat([df_id, df_row, df_columns ], axis=1, join='inner')

result
```

But I couldn't get the structure that I want.

Any help is appreciated on this challenge.

If there is any similar solution in this community, kindly let me know.

Comment: _But I couldn’t get the structure that I want._ Can you be more specific? I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: start by posting a valid xml - the current one is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<Tables>
  <Table ID="1" Row="3" Column="5">  
     <Text> Example 1 </Text>    
  </Table>

 <Table ID="2" Row="4" Column="3">
    <Text> Example 2 </Text>
 </Table>
</Tables>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = [{'id': t.attrib['ID'],'row': t.attrib['Row'],'col': t.attrib['Column'],'text':t.find('Text').text} for t in root.findall('.//Table')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot.